# Projective resolution of a $K[t]$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module, polynomial-rings

Let $K$ be some field. I want to show that every indecomposable right $K[t]$-module $M$ is has a projective resolution of the form $$0 \to P_1 \to P_0 \to M \to 0.$$
To that end, I have a hint: Such a module $M$ must be of the form $$M = \displaystyle{\frac{K[t]}{\langle p(t) \rangle}}$$ with $\langle p(t) \rangle = p(t) K[t]$, for $p(t)$ the power of some irreducible polynomial in $K[t]$.

My attempt was to show that both $\langle p(t) \rangle$ and $K[t]$ are projective $K[t]$-modules. The latter is clear, as every ring is projective over itself, but the first is giving me trouble. So I have a couple of questions:

- Is this strategy the best one, or there is some other path I should take?
- Is there some *hint* on how to prove that $\langle p(t) \rangle$ is projective?

If I wanted to prove the hint (and I am clueless on how to prove it), could someone hint me on how to start it?

Comment: By the way, I am aware that there are more than one question on this post. If you think I should split it into multiple questions, please, let me know.

Comment: Hint: $\langle p(t) \rangle=p(t) K[t]\cong K[t]$.

Comment: Yup. This pretty much solves it. Thanks!